# How can I recognize the value directly in useCallback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I want to run console.log('success') when myFood[myFood.length - 1]?.id and viewable Items[viewable Items.length - 1]?.item?.id are equal.

But for example, console.log('success)' is not executed even though both values ​​match.

There seems to be some problem getting the value of myFood[myFood.length - 1]?.id. How do I fix the code?

```
     myFood = [

0: {id: 16, name: "13", content1: "1", content2: "2", content3: "3", …}
1: {id: 15, name: "12", content1: "1", content2: "2", content3: "3", …}
2: {id: 14, name: "11", content1: "1", content2: "2", content3: "3", …}
3: {id: 13, name: "10", content1: "1", content2: "2", content3: "3", …}
4: {id: 12, name: "9", content1: "1", content2: "2", content3: "3", …}
5: {id: 11, name: "8", content1: "1", content2: "2", content3: "3", …}
6: {id: 10, name: "7", content1: "1", content2: "2", content3: "3", …}
7: {id: 9, name: "6", content1: "1", content2: "2", content3: "3", …}
8: {id: 8, name: "5", content1: "1", content2: "2", content3: "3", …}   
9: {id: 7, name: "4", content1: "1", content2: "2", content3: "3", …}
             ]
```

this is my code

```
    const {myFood, loaduserhasMorePosts, loadPostsLoading} = useSelector(
      (state) => state.post,
    );

    myFood[myFood.length - 1]?.id; //7

    
    const onViewableItemsChanged = useCallback(
      async ({viewableItems}) => {
        if (
          myFood[myFood.length - 1]?.id ===
          viewableItems[viewableItems.length - 1]?.item?.id //7
        ) {
          console.log('success');
        }
      },
      [hey, myFood],
    )
        return (
        <>
          <FlatList
            viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs={viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs.current}
  
            data={myFood}
          
          />
        </>
      );
```

Comment: are you getting any errors on inspection console?  just to be sure write console.log(myFood); and console.log(viewableItems);  lines before "if" and read the results from inspection console. See if your indexes are correct and if corresponding objects have appropriate values. Paste results here in comments or add it your question.

Comment: I wonder why you return const?

Comment: @RamanNikitsenka sorry i made a mistake i just edited

Comment: useCallback will just give you a memoized a function it doesn't call the function for you. So you need to call it manually in your code . Are you calling the `onViewableItemsChanged` function , if yes then can you add that code as well ?

Comment: yeap, where do you assign/use "onViewableItemsChanged" in your code ?

Comment: @Shyam i just updated my code can you check?

Comment: @AntiqTech  i just updated my code can you check?

Comment: I'm checking but "onViewableItemsChanged" still seems unused. What am I missing ?

Comment: The `return` appears outside a function context, and `myFood[myFood.length - 1]?.id;` is without effect, as it is not assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are expecting the first argument to `useCallback` to be executed and therefore logging to the console:

```
const onViewableItemsChanged = useCallback(
  async ({viewableItems}) => {
    if (
      myFood[myFood.length - 1]?.id ===
      viewableItems[viewableItems.length - 1]?.item?.id //7
    ) {
      console.log('success');
    }
  },
  [hey, myFood],
)
```

The [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) method creates a memoized callback, it does not execute the method you are passing to it. As explained in the documentation, useCallback is just a special case of [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), which returns a memoized value.

```
const str = 'foo';
const fn = () => str;
const deps = [str];
const callback1 = useCallback(fn, deps); // equivalent to callback2
const callback2 = useMemo(() => fn, deps); // equivalent to callback1
```

If you are not familiar with memoization, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization#:%7E:text=In%20computing%2C%20memoization%20or%20memoisation,the%20same%20inputs%20occur%20again.) has a good explanation.
I also noticed that in your code:

1. `hey` is undefined
2. `hey` is never used in the callback that you are passing in the first argument to `useCallback`

The documentation for `useCallback` mention the following:

> The array of dependencies is not passed as arguments to the callback. Conceptually, though, that’s what they represent: every value referenced inside the callback should also appear in the dependencies array. In the future, a sufficiently advanced compiler could create this array automatically.

Including it in the dependencies will cause the memoized value to be recomputed more than necessary.